# Data.subdata(in:) results in EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, exc-bad-instruction

While trying to retrieve subdata of a `Data` object, the application crashes issuing the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Below you can see the code. It's a `Data` extension. Hope someone can explain why this crashes.

```
public extension Data {
    /// Removes and returns the range of data at the specified position.
    /// - Parameter range: The range to remove. `range` must be valid
    /// for the collection and should not exceed the collection's end index.
    /// - Returns: The removed data.
    mutating func remove(at range: Range<Data.Index>) -> Self {
        precondition(range.lowerBound >= 0, "Range invalid, lower bound cannot be below 0")
        precondition(range.upperBound < self.count, "Range invalid, upper bound exceeds data size")
        
        let removal = subdata(in: range) // <- Error occurs here
        removeSubrange(range)
        return removal
    }
}
```

EDIT - added the caller functions:

This extension is called from the following function:

```
func temporary(data: inout Data) -> Data {
    let _ = data.removeFirst()
    return data.remove(range: 0 ..< 3)
}
```

Which in turn is called like this:

```
var data = Data([0,1,2,3,4,5])
let subdata = temporary(data: &data)
```

Comment: `Data` conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`. Why don't you use `removeSubrange`? Btw `Data.Index` is just a typeAlias to `Int`

Comment: Note that `removeSubrange` works for any `RangeExpression`

Comment: `removeSubrange` doesn't return the removed data. I need the removed data similar to `data.removeFirst()` which returns the `UInt8` that was removed. `removeSubrange` performs the operation correctly, but returns `Void`.

Comment: Do you want me to show how this should be implemented? I mean a generic method that would be like removeSubrange but returns what is being removed. I would also remove the preconditions

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes please!

Comment: Btw your pre condition is wrong

Comment: Why? Range can go below zero, while the index of a collection cannot and the upperbound can never be greater or equal than the amount of bytes in the collection. If the collection is 100 bytes long, the max index is 99. I believe my preconditions are correct...

Comment: try `var data = Data([0,1,2,3,4,5])`
`let subdata = data.remove(at: 0..<6)` it wiill throw **Precondition failed: Range invalid, upper bound exceeds data size** Range upper bound can be equal to count

Comment: Ah, right. So the `count >= 0` is correct, the other one should be `count <= upperBound`, of course!

Comment: No. it should be the opposite  `upperbound <= count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the `removeFirst` function. The documentation clearly states:

> Calling this method may invalidate all saved indices of this collection. Do not rely on a previously stored index value after altering a collection with any operation that can change its length.

It appears that is exactly what is causing my error. I have replaced `removeFirst` with `remove(at:)` and it now works.

Comment: Every now and again I forget about this and then I make something that just crashes and after going crazy to fix it for several hours find this post again and remember how silly it is that I keep forgetting it. I wish we could highlight this more.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information for us to know the reason of your crash. One thing that I know that is wrong in your method is your precondition. You wont be able to pass a range to remove all elements of your collection. Besides that you should implement a generic method that would take a RangeExpression instead of a Range. This is how I would implement such method:

```
extension Data {
    /// Removes and returns the range of data at the specified position.
    /// - Parameter range: The range to remove. `range` must be valid
    /// for the collection and should not exceed the collection's end index.
    /// - Returns: The removed data.
    mutating func remove<R>(_ range: R) -> Data where R: RangeExpression, Index == R.Bound {
        defer { removeSubrange(range) }
        return subdata(in: range.relative(to: self))
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var data = Data([0,1,2,3,4,5])
let subdata = data.remove(0..<6)
print(Array(data), Array(subdata))  // "[] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]\n"
```

To check if your data indices contains a specific range before attempting to remove you can use pattern-matching operator:

```
var data = Data([0,1,2,3,4,5])
let range = 0..<7
if data.indices ~= range {
    let subdata = data.remove(range)
    print(Array(data), Array(subdata))
} else {
    print("invalid subrange")  // "invalid subrange\n"
}
```

If you would like to do the same with a ClosedRange you would need to implement your own pattern-matching operator on Range:

```
extension Range {
    static func ~=(lhs: Self, rhs: ClosedRange<Bound>) -> Bool {
        lhs.contains(rhs.lowerBound) && lhs.contains(rhs.upperBound)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var data = Data([0,1,2,3,4,5])
let range = 0...5
if data.indices ~= range {
    let subdata = data.remove(range)
    print(Array(data), Array(subdata))  // "[] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]\n"
} else {
    print("invalid subrange")
}
```

Comment: This is similar to an earlier implementation I had. This does still give me an error. I have reasons to believe that this may be due some lazy loading and/or properties, which means some of the data is not yet present at the time of executing this code. Kind of explains the bad instruction error, as by the time the debugger is attached, the memory is loaded

Comment: You should always check the data indices before removing any content

Comment: Can you elaborate on _check indices_?

Comment: I've updated my question with the calling functions. The error persists.